# Error in link Admin Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, pagination, dashboard

I made a website migration http:// web.dominio.com.br to http:// www.dominio.com.br, I did not change folder just url, changed the siteurl and the home in wp_options, I one replace the wp_posts, wp_options and wp_postmeta, changing the url's, the site and the menu function properly, but is showing an error in pagination in Admin,. When access all Posts and I click to Sort by Date or to go to the next page it is calling the old url, http://web.dominio.com.br/wp-admin/edit.php?orderby=date&order=desc

Has anyone experienced this or have any idea what might be this error?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to redefine the WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL variables. Place this in your wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.dominio.com.br');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.dominio.com.br');
```

Comment: I've done this change inclusive 
<code>
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (
guid,
'http://web.dominio.com/',
'http://www.dominio.com/');
</code>
and tables wp_options , wp_postmeta